# Using async / await inside async.auto chain leads to TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, async-await, async.js

**What version of async are you using?**

2.6.1

**Which environment did the issue occur in (Node version/browser version)**

8.11.3

**What did you do? Please include a minimal reproducible case illustrating the issue.**

Assuming fileObj is supplied from outside:

```
async.auto({
  download: (downloadCB) => {
    if (fileObj) {
      fs.writeFile(__dirname + ‘fileNew.txt’, fileObj.content, 'base64', function (err) {
        if (err){
          return downloadCB(err);
        }
        return downloadCB(null , fileObj.generatedFileName); // works fine
      });
    } else {
      let err = new Error('File not found');
      return downloadCB(err);
    }
  },
  collectData: ['download', async (results, collectCB) => {
    console.log(typeof collectCB); // prints undefined
    console.log(typeof results); // prints correct object

    let res = await anHttpRequest();
    if (res.response && res.response.statusCode == 200) {
      return collectCB(null , 'fileCombined.txt'); // This is where the ISSUE happens
    }
    else if(res.response.statusCode >= 300) {
      return collectCB(new Error('Request failed inside async-auto'));
    }
  }],

  filterData: ['collectData', (results, filterCB) => {
    doFilter(results.collectData, filterCB);
  }],
})
```

**What did you expect to happen?**

After collectData finishes execution, filterData should begin execution the param passed inside collectCB function

**What was the actual result?**

TypeError: collectCB is not a function.

The same code executes well with version 2.0.1 but after upgrade to 2.6.1 it has stopped working and its critical for us. Any work arounds will also be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX, I posted the same issue on their GitHub page but didn't get any response till now, so cross-posting it here, opening it to a larger audience, in hope anyone can help. Its a bit critical currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html) (quoted in the other answer already but here it is again)

> Wherever we accept a Node-style async function, we also directly accept an ES2017 async function. In this case, the async function will not be passed a final callback argument, and any thrown error will be used as the err argument of the implicit callback, and the return value will be used as the result value. (i.e. a rejected of the returned Promise becomes the err callback argument, and a resolved value becomes the result.)

what you would do is

```
async.auto({
    download: (downloadCB) => {
        if (fileObj) {
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + ‘fileNew.txt’, fileObj.content, 'base64', function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return downloadCB(err);
                }
                return downloadCB(null, fileObj.generatedFileName); // works fine
            });
        } else {
            let err = new Error('File not found');
            return downloadCB(err);
        }
    },
    //                                      Note, no callback as per documentation
    collectData: ['download', async (results) => {
        console.log(typeof results); // prints correct object

        let res = await anHttpRequest();

        if (res.response && res.response.statusCode == 200) {
            // this return is equivalent to callback(null, value);
            return 'fileCombined.txt';
        } else if (res.response.statusCode >= 300) {
            // this throw is equivalent to callback(err);
            throw new Error('Request failed inside async-auto');
        }
        // but surely something should be here!? for status code 201-209?
    }],

    filterData: ['collectData', (results, filterCB) => {
        doFilter(results.collectData, filterCB);
    }],
})
```

Comment: Thanks! The added code helped a lot understanding the documentation.

Comment: which is the *final callback* @n.bharath - did you read the quoted documentation? **In this case, the async function will not be passed a final callback argument**

Answer (score 1):

Just a copy-paste from the official [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html):

> Wherever we accept a Node-style async function, we also directly
>   accept an ES2017 async function. In this case, the async function **will
>   not be passed a final callback argument**, and any thrown error will be
>   used as the err argument of the implicit callback, and the return
>   value will be used as the result value. (i.e. a rejected of the
>   returned Promise becomes the err callback argument, and a resolved
>   value becomes the result.)